# Assistance on SQL Case statement for selecting from a column that Might have a comma

Tags: sql, db2, case, locate

I'm attempting to add a column to a view in which I'm using the following code to pull only the Last name from a field that is formatted 'LastName,FirstName':

```
VALUE(RTRIM(SUBSTR(A.PREVIOUS_NAMES,1,LOCATE(',', A.PREVIOUS_NAMES)-1)), '') 
AS "PREVIOUS_NAME",
```

This works fine when there is a comma in the field, however, as referenced from the following question, the view errors when a comma is not present.
[SQLCode=-138 flagging on large count tables but not small DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204938/sqlcode-138-flagging-on-large-count-tables-but-not-small-db2/46204965#46204965)

I've tried to come up with a case statement to accommodate this, to select when the comma is present, but I've been unsuccessful, and I'm seeking assistance or suggestions from experienced people.

```
RTRIM(
   CASE WHEN LOCATE(",", A.PREVIOUS_NAMES) = 0 
   THEN A.PREVIOUS_NAMES 
   ELSE SUBSTR(A.PREVIOUS_NAMES,1,LOCATE(",", A.PREVIOUS_NAMES)-1) 
   END) AS "PREVIOUS_NAME"
```

It's not very sophisticated, and it gives me SQLcode-206 saying ", is not valid in the context it is used".

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this in DB2, but a common method around this is to add a comma:

```
VALUE(RTRIM(SUBSTR(A.PREVIOUS_NAMES, 1, LOCATE(',', A.PREVIOUS_NAMES || ',') - 1)), '') 
AS "PREVIOUS_NAME",
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you so much Gordon.